# set.add(x) vs. x in set: What is faster?

Tags: python, algorithm

A lot of algorithmic task inputs include duplicates analysis in different forms. In cases like this set() is an excellent suggestion for the data structure.

Assume input data includes a lot of duplicates. There are 2 ways how to add them to the final set of unique values:

1. Just add: `my_set.add(x)` and keep Python to do the job
2. Check for presence and add if not present:

```py
if x not in my_set:
  my_set.add(x)
```

Which one is faster? Ask python to hash new value and re-add if present or explicitly check for presence? Or maybe python does something smart, and every time .add() is called it makes this check implicitly?

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity to try benchmarking both options

Comment: By what possible logic can "check for X; do Y" take less time than "do Y"?

Comment: @ScottHunter. I'm sure I can come up with an example if I think hard enough, but your point is valid nevertheless. Especially when Y is literally "only actually do Y if not X"

Comment: `x in my_set or my_set.add(x)`.  But I agree with @ScottHunter

Comment: One piece of code does `X`. the other does `Y` and then `X`. Which one is faster? Obviously just doing `X` in 99% of the cases (there are a couple of degenerate cases with branch prediction/cpu caches that might make doing `Y+X` faster, but in python this is unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

Both `x.add(set)` and `x not in set` have to compute the hash of `x` and (a) check if the hash is present (b) if so, check if `x` is in the corresponding bucket. It is reasonable that any implementation of `add` exits immediately if the check succeeds, which makes it equivalent to doing the check manually, but much faster.

Answer (score 1):

A quick experiment to confirm that no replacement takes place in the event of a match:

```
# versions of CPython tested: 2.4.0, 2.7.8, 2.7.15, 3.2.3, 3.4.4, 3.7.1

# custom hashable object
>>> class Foo:
...   def __init__(self, a, b):
...     self.key = a
...     self.value = b
...   def __hash__(self):
...     # only hash the keys
...     return hash(self.key)
...   def __eq__(self, c):
...     return c.key == self.key

# create two objects with the same key but different values
>>> a = Foo(0xdead, 0xbeef)
>>> b = Foo(0xdead, 0xcafe)

# add the first item
>>> c = set()
>>> c.add(a)
>>> c
{<__main__.Foo object at 0x00000000032045F8>}
>>> hex(list(c)[0].value)
'0xbeef'

# confirm that a duplicate exists
>>> b in c
True

# try to add the second anyway
>>> c.add(b)

# the original item was not replaced, as expected (would have printed '0xcafe' instead)
>>> c
{<__main__.Foo object at 0x00000000032045F8>}
>>> hex(list(c)[0].value)
'0xbeef'
```

Not mandated by [the specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), but a reasonable assumption to make like the others have said.